# How to Know status of the Connection between Web service and client in php?

Tags: php, web-services, cakephp

i have create a REST web service using cakephp 2.7 in i have create a service for createpost. if user is create the post using web service and post is created and before send the response to the client. client side occure net issue so client not get response or i want to find out the client is still connected with web service or not? if not then send a email with post details to client.

Comment: PHP is a server side language. You cannot poll the client for activity. You can use jQuery or websockets to do this though.

Comment: You don't. REST is stateless. You might want to read about how REST works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer